# getting error for org.msgpack.MessagePack when using fluent-logger-java

Tags: fluentd

I get "Could not initialize class org.msgpack.MessagePack"  when I try using the class I created that uses fluent-logger-java.
and referencing: fluent-logger-0.3.2.jar  & msgpack-0.6.12.jar or msgpack-core-0.7.0-p7.jar

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

downloading fluent-logger-java from here resolved the issue:  https://github.com/fluent/fluent-logger-java#install-with-all-in-one-jar-file